# Extremely slow R Studio Server <-> Athena integration?

Tags: amazon-athena, rstudio-server

I have a set up in which I create 4 very large tables (600,000,000 +rows) on athena, split by columns. I am trying to import subsets of these athena tables into R Studio, run on a m4.16.xlarge, but imports are extraordinarily slow. For example, 10 MIllion rows will take ~ 50 minutes to import - not exactly Big Data friendly cloud computing.

```r
dbListTables(athenaconnect) % connection works
query = "SELECT 
           maid_matched_voterfile_maid_1.maid,
           vb_voterbase_age,
           vb_voterbase_gender,
           ts_tsmart_urbanicity,
           --  
           ts_tsmart_high_school_only_score,
           ts_tsmart_college_graduate_score,                
           ts_tsmart_partisan_score,
           ts_tsmart_presidential_general_turnout_score,
           vb_voterbase_marital_status,
           vb_tsmart_census_id,
           vb_voterbase_deceased_flag 
       FROM 
           maid_matched_voterfile_maid_1
       LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT 
              maid, 
              ts_tsmart_urbanicity,
              ts_tsmart_partisan_score, 
              ts_tsmart_presidential_general_turnout_score
          FROM 
              maid_matched_voterfile_maid_4
          ) maid_matched_voterfile_maid_4
       ON 
          maid_matched_voterfile_maid_1.maid = maid_matched_voterfile_maid_4.maid
       WHERE 
          SUBSTR(vb_tsmart_census_id,1,2) = '42'"
q <- dbSendQuery(athenaconnect, query)
pa_voterfile <- fetch(q, -1, block=999)
```

Any ideas as to how I can speed up these processes? I am expecting to load ~10 Million rows/7-8 columns in ~ 5 minutes (which even a simple data.table based fread could handle I think). Thank you!

Comment: 4 Tables with 600,000,000 rows, not 600,000 rows of course....

Comment: Is your data partitioned and also have you tried best practices as mentioned in https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/ . ?

Comment: If you run that query directly on Athena, e.g. using the AWS console, how long does it take?

Comment: If you're importing data via a JDBC driver for example, 10 million rows is going to take a long time to process. I'm not familiar with R but if it can access a parquet file directly, maybe use a CTAS statement in Athena to create a new parquet file (or files) with the data you want to analyse, then copy that file from S3 locally onto your server?